# Codeigniter - Amending an existing view using a module?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I amend a view using a module in Codeigniter?

Currently, there is a view file in the `root/Application/Views/Themes/Theme/dashboard.php`

I've created a module and have it working.

The new view will be in the folder below:

```
root/modules/module_name/views/dashboard.php
```

I want to amend the dashboard.php file without touching the main 'dashboard.php' file.

Do I use a controller or just create a new view.

Comment: if you planning not touching the old one, where you will put the new one? new route?

Comment: I created a module and planned on adding the view in the module this way I'll be able to deactivate the module if I have no need for the changes in the dashboard.php file.

Comment: So the new location of the file root/modules/module_folder/views/dashboard.php